# Cannot install R packages because "make" is not found, although Rtools is installed and PATH is included

Tags: r, makefile, package

I am trying to run a packrat:restore() to restore all libraries in my project. When I run the command I get the following message:

[image]

So it looks like the 'make' command is not present so that is why the package cannot be build. This executable is located in Rtools. I have Rtools 3.5 installed on my computer. The directory is in the PATH variable:

[image]

And sure enough I find make executable in the directory

[image]

However when I run the command Sys.which it doesn't return the path to the executable:

[image]

I don't understand what the problem is. I have googled this issues and it was either suggested to install the new version of Rtools (however I am running R version 3.6.1, and the newest version of Rtools is for R version 4.x, so this doesn't make sense for me because I don't want to install the new R version), or to add the path of Rtools to the PATH, but is already configured.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Rok

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: BTW, is there a specific reason you're remaining on an old version of R? 3.6.1 was released in July 2019; in Dec 2019, R-3.6.2 was released; Feb 2020 R-3.6.3; each of those should be an "easy upgrade" (unlikely to break anything). Since then, we've had two larger upgrades (R-4.0 in Apr 2020, and R-4.1 in May 2021), and we're going to have R-4.2 fairly soon ([allegedly 2022-04-22](https://developer.r-project.org/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you cannot have spaces in your `PATH`.

To test on my system, I started with a `PATH` without access to `make.exe`.

```r
Sys.which("make")
# make 
#   "" 
file.exists("c:/rtools40/usr/bin/make.exe")
# [1] TRUE

oldpath <- Sys.getenv("PATH")
grepl("rtools", oldpath, ignore.case = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(oldpath, "; c:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin"))
Sys.which("make")
# make 
#   "" 
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(oldpath, ";c:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin"))
Sys.which("make")
#                               make 
# "c:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```

Incidentally, if you don't like all of the double-backslashes, even on windows R can use the forward-slash as its `.Platform$file.sep`.

```r
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste0(oldpath, ";c:/rtools40/usr/bin"))
Sys.which("make")
#                               make 
# "c:\\rtools40\\usr\\bin\\make.exe"
```